# I want to display a login component over my welcome component in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular5, angular2-routing, angular-ui

I want to display a login component over on welcome component when user click the login button login screen will be disappeared and welcome screen will be visible the reason for doing this is i am using a license token validation in my app that check license token every 1min if license token renew failed login screen will come again ,if the user is valid he can use the application where he left off

Comment: sounds like a plan! you can use this.router.navigate(['/welcome'']) after login. are you looking for something more advanced?

Comment: this way component will be reinitialized  so its not a good  idea i think?

Comment: then you can expose a licensetokenstatus from the service that is checking licenses and use ng-if to display login/welcome in the view.

Comment: yes but how to display a component over other one

Comment: you can use css, z-index

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular routing for the same within your project  structure include

**route.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/index';
import { WelcomeComponent} from './welcome/index';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: '/welcome', component: WelcomeComponent}
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
...
import { routing } from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
....,
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    routing
  ],
....
```

**LoginComponent.html**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/welcome']">Login</a>
```

Remember to make Login as an anchor tag as link doesn't works on button

what you can do i believe renewToken would be part of a service which will be subscribed and if it fails the desired result on subscription and get the previous route with something like this

```
router.events
  .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .subscribe(e => {
    console.log('prev:', this.previousUrl);
    this.previousUrl = e.url;
  });


 then in the next() post subscription call
```

`this.router.navigate([`caratSign${this.previousUrl}caratSign`])`

Comment: this will not meet the requirement, i want user to start where he left the application in case of token renew failed

Comment: added few more tips  @user3082970

Comment: there are n number of screen in my application user can not jump to other screen  without filling details in previous screen suppose in case license token renew failed for some reason like network problem application will jump to login screen he need to start again from scratch to overcome this issue i want one component over other so that i can display that component when token renew failed no matter on which screen it is

Comment: i m able to nagivate to previous url but header and footer are reinitialized again

Comment: you can solve that by including common header and footer by making them seperate components and including them on your main component/app component  like 
`<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>`

Comment: they are not a part of login screen apart from that they are common for every screen

Comment: let them be part of main component itself and hide them on the loginScreen based on some flag which becomes true only if your route is login use *ngIf and create a common-header-footer service to manipulate them

Comment: i have a issue let me explain it properly when my token renew fail application jump to login screen then when i click again it jumps to previous screen  but now my app header has a notification array which is getting double on each time when the token renew fail and i login again

Comment: i dont know y this is happening i m setting it only once